# How to Display two alert dialogs in specific order?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have two alert dialogs. Whenever app opens, the first dialog is shown. After some time, the second dialog is shown. But here problem is recently created dialog(second one) is in front. But I want the fist created dialog is in front and second one is behind the first one.

Comment: Try using DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog.

Comment: Do you want two dialog active in same time????

Comment: no, I want first created dialog is in active mode and second one is should be disable until first is gone away.

Comment: What event triggers the alertdialogs? Wouldn't it be possible to make the second alert dialog show up when the first one is closed? Or maybe you can check if the first dialog is open then dismiss the second one and show it again after the first dialog is closed

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the dialog box is that you can not display two dialog box at a same time. You must hide first dialog box in order to display second one.

Comment: No,I want to show first dialog is always in front and second one behind first one.

Comment: @user3301551 how said `you can not display two dialog box at a same time`??

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan that is because you can not display second dialogbox over the first one.

Comment: Hey ..! I mentioned, they were created at different time not same time.

Comment: @KumarKalluri what do you mean by different time ?

Comment: Second one will be created after the first one is created

Comment: @KumarKalluri agree but you can not display one dialog over the another one that's what I am trying to explain you. So you must hide or dispose first dialog if you want to display second one.

Comment: I want to display always first dialog box not second dialog box.  or how can i disable second dialog box until first dialog box is gone away?

Comment: @KumarKalluri for that thing I need to see your coding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47321/discussion-between-kumar-kalluri-and-user3301551)

Comment: These dialogs are not created from same class. These are created from different classes as part of their functionlaity.

Comment: So you want to display one by one dialog which are invoked from different activities, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only display one dialog at the time, but you can "work around" this. When you are about to display your second dialog, you hide your first dialog, but your application remembers that the first dialog was open, so when you hide your second dialog you displays the first dialog again. In reality this will go so fast so the user is fooled that the dialog is layered over eachother(if they have the same dimensions).
But you cannot display a dialog on top of another dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can display first dialog in front :

When you are calling to display second one at that time call first dialog again so, that is in from view of your screen.

Let me know you understand this or not.. otherwise i will provide code for it..

Comment: These dialogs are not created from same class. These are created from different classes as part of their functionlaity.

Comment: Either its activity or fragment you cant display two active dialog same time one should active and the other should inactive.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make two `dialog` active at same time either one should `active` and the other should `inactive`.In your case if you want the second should come background of fist then you have to call `first dialog` from the `second`.